# Problem when compile gnumeric from source

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, gnumeric

I'm trying to compile gnumeric 1.12.45 from source.
The building is done and it works but when the windows open, it shows a lot of warnings.

For example, there are multiple lines of warnings like this,

```
CRITICAL **: 19:10:06.028: go_conf_add_monitor: assertion 'node || key' failed
CRITICAL **: 19:10:06.028: go_conf_get_node: assertion 'parent || key' failed
```

and it show multiple lines of `WARNING **: 19:11:16.979: unknown GOConfMonitor id.` when I closed the windows.

What should I add or configure to make it disappear when I run the binary?